# TableView Controller is hiding the dropshadow of swipemenu in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I am using SwipeMenu bar controller in my project development, which just look like a slide bar in android devices. In swipe controller there are multiple tabs. I added table view controller for one tab and for another is just view controller. When i apply drop shadow for that, in first tab shadow is not appearing. and in second tab it appears. In first tab table view controller is hiding the drop shadow. Please help.

```
Swipe Menu code is as follows
------------------------------

    final class TransactionsViewController:SwipeMenuViewController {
       private var datas: [String] = ["TAB1","TAB2", "TAB3", "TAB4","TAB5" ]
       var dataCount: Int = 5
       var viewControllerToLoad = ""
       override func viewDidLoad() {

           datas.forEach { data in
               print(data)
               if(data == "TAB1"){
                   viewControllerToLoad = "tab1View"
               }else if(data == "TAB2"){
                   viewControllerToLoad = "tab2View"
               }else if(data == "TAB3"){
                   viewControllerToLoad = "tab3View"
               }else if(data == "TAB4"){
                   viewControllerToLoad = "tab4View"
               }else if(data == "TAB5"){
                   viewControllerToLoad = "tab5View"
               }
               let vc =   UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerToLoad)
               vc.title = data
               self.addChildViewController(vc)
           }
           super.viewDidLoad()
           reload()
        }
    }

DropShadow Code
----------------

    xtension UIView {
       func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
           layer.masksToBounds = false
           layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
           layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
           layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 3)
           layer.shadowRadius = 7.0
       }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAir0.png)

Comment: Where is your code? )

Comment: Code included in the post now. please check.